# Entity Framework: sort linked entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given the following entity class, which represents an item in a linked list of items, how can we sort using LINQ these items (in the order defined by `NextItemId`) , such that the query is translated to SQL and done on the database side?

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; } 

    public virtual int? NextItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item NextItem { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. In my system, where I need to implement somewhat similar feature to this, I use an indexed `varchar` field to keep the full path of the item like

```
Id     NextItemId     ItemPath
1      2              /1
2      9              /1/2
9      13             /1/2/9
```

This way you can query by using `where ItemPath.StartsWith()` and utilise the index too.